# Build command failed using Fastlane to build app on TestFlight

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, testflight, fastlane

I'm currently trying to build my react native app on TestFlight with Fastlane using this [tutorial](https://www.boorje.com/deploy-react-native-app/)

I reached the last step and ran the command
`bundle exec fastlane beta`
This should've built the app on TestFlight, but it didn't.

Instead, I received this error: `File/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GAbeta-etzidujiozhpelfdovtuwdoldqcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GAbeta/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/GAbeta.app/main.jsbundle does not exist.`

Additionally, I was informed that the following build commands failed:
`PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GAbeta-etzidujiozhpelfdovtuwdoldqcl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/GAbeta/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/GAbeta.build/Release-iphoneos/GAbeta.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh`

I've done some research on potential [solutions](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25522#issuecomment-509036251), but none worked.

Does anyone have any suggestions in order to solve this issue or could anyone potentially assist in my search?

Additionally, I apologize if my formatting in asking this question was incorrect, this is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow.